# django newbie - varying template table style by day of the week

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I have a table in a template, and one of the columns of each row of the table is a date object.  The table rows are sorted by date.  I want to shade all the rows of a particular date, then unshade all the rows of the next day, then shade all the rows that match the next day, etc. etc.

I know how to figure out the day of the week for each day (using date.weekday) so I can test to see if the day for the current row matches a comparison value, then shade or not shade as the case may be, but I don't know how to make the shading/not shading alternate with each new day.

I'm sure it's relatively simple but it's late and my brain isn't working well.  Any help is appreciated.  Here's an example of the table WITHOUT the shading I'd like to see.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best way to do this is use a specific class from date:

```
<tr {% if date.day|divisibleby:"2" %}class="date_even"{% else %}class="date_odd"{% endif %}>
    <td>something</td>
    <td>something else</td>
    <td>{{ date }}</td>
</tr>
```

And then with css do the rest

Comment: Thanks very much.  I think you've given me an idea of how to do it.  I think checking the odd/even of a counter is the way to go, but I think I'll have to do it in the view and pass the class value to the template, since I don't want each row to alternate in color; instead, I'll want all rows of the same day to be the same color.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to `divisibleby` is to use [`cycle`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/templates/builtins/#cycle) to just cycle through the classes:

```
{% for row in table %}
<tr class="{% cycle 'row_odd' 'row_even' %}">
...
```

Comment: Awesome, this was the best solution for me.